# Time complexity of code with nested while loop

Tags: while-loop, time-complexity

I am trying to figure out the time complexity of the following code

```
n=int(input()
l=list(map(int,input().split()))

j=0
k=0
c=0

while(k+j!=n):
    c=c+2*l[n-1-j]
    j=j+1

    while(c>=0 and k+j!=n):
        c=c-l[k]
        k=k+1

print(k,j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotically worst-case in O(n^2) because each while can could be executed n times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in practice i got time complexity almost equal to O(n) for all test cases.